# neo4j 3.2 community edition: browser console does not reliably return relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Version:  Neo4j 3.2.0, Community Edition
Environment:  macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Browser: Safari 11.0

I am seeing inconsistent behavior in how the browser console for `neo4j` returns relationships.  I demonstrate with a very simple example:

```
CREATE (g:Whale {color: "gray"}) WITH g
CREATE (b:Whale {color: "blue"}) WITH g, b
MERGE (g)-[:SWIMS_WITH]->(b)
RETURN g, b
```

This works as expected.  Now, let's see if we can just return the `:SWIMS_WITH` relationship.

```
MATCH (g:Whale {color: "gray"}) WITH g
MATCH (b:Whale {color: "blue"}) WITH g, b
MATCH (g)-[sw:SWIMS_WITH]->(b)
RETURN sw
```

Browser console response indicates that `0 nodes, 0 relationships` were returned.  But what if we return the path:

```
MATCH (g:Whale {color: "gray"}) WITH g
MATCH (b:Whale {color: "blue"}) WITH g, b
MATCH p=(g)-[sw:SWIMS_WITH]->(b)
RETURN p
```

This query correctly locates and displays the 2 nodes and single link connecting them.  Making things further confusing, if I attach a property to the `:SWIM_WITH` relationship, then the query will properly return the relationship (with said property):

```
MATCH (g:Whale {color: "gray"}) WITH g
MATCH (b:Whale {color: "blue"}) WITH g, b
MATCH (g)-[sw:SWIMS_WITH]->(b)
SET sw.speed = "22 knots"
RETURN sw
```

I am hoping this is purely a bug in the `neo4j` browser console.  But if it's something else, please say so.

Comment: maybe add an issue to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser

Comment: "Browser console response indicates that 0 nodes, 0 relationships were returned" -- it does return the result for me: "Started streaming 1 records after 1 ms and completed after 1 ms." and it returns a single relationship, which is shown in table/text mode. Spec: Ubuntu 16.04, 3.2.5 community edition, Google Chrome

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using? Going by Gabor's comments, this may be a bug in an older version that has since been fixed.

Comment: 3.2, per original posting.

Comment: There is no 3.2 version actually. It is always 3.2.x (and the x is the important thing here).

Comment: Thx.. just re-edited original post to reflect 3.2.0 version.

Comment: You should upgrade to 3.2.6. Lots of browser visualization issues (there is nothing wrong with your data) have been resolved since 3.2.0 and any version later than 3.2.3 definitely does not have your issue.